Identity element in universal covering group
I am reading a paragraph about universal covering groups in J. Lee, "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds". It is said there that having topological covering $\tilde{G}$ of Lie group $G$ one can choose an arbitrary element of $\pi^{-1}(e)$ to be an identity in $\tilde{G}$, where $\pi$ is a covering, map. But this means, that, for example, in case of $\pi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$ such that $\pi(x)=e^{2\pi i x}$, we can choose some non-trivial number in $\mathbb{Z}$ to be identity in Lie group $\tilde{G}=\mathbb{R}$, for example, $\tilde{e}=2$.
I can't understand how one should preform standard group operations (addition and taking inverse) in this case? It seems like a standard way to define it on $\mathbb{R}$ (meaning $m(a, b)=a+b, i(a)=-a$) won't work here since, at least, $i(\tilde{e})=i(2)=-2\neq \tilde{e}$.

Choosing a different (non-standard) identity changes the group operation.  The group operation in the cover comes from (a) the group operation in the base space and (b) a choice of identity element from the fiber.  The proof of this fact constructs the group operation explicitly.

@Randall, please do write your comment out as an answer... :)

@paulgarrett I would, but I do not think it is a complete answer.  A good answer would give the construction of the operation as the result of a lifting [which then makes the dependence on the choice in the fiber clear], but I have neither the time nor patience for that right now.  Maybe someone will come along and flesh this out.

@Randall, reasonable. :)  Ok, then I'll just insert a keyword/phrase here, "choice of basepoint". E.g., homotopy groups need a choice of basepoint, otherwise they're just "groupoids" (which may be more natural...).

Well I just lied and wrote up an answer anyway.

Let $p: \tilde{G} \to G$ be your universal cover.  Recall that a lift $\tilde{f}$ of a map $f: X \to G$ for "nice" $X$ is unique once a point in the fiber $e_0 \in p^{-1}(e)$ is chosen so that $\tilde{f}(x_0)=e$.  ("Nice" probably means locally path connected and simply connected.)  Here, everything is based and the basepoint for $G$ is taken to be its identity element.
So, let's first choose a point $e_0$ from the fiber $p^{-1}(e)$.   Now consider the composite
$$
f: \tilde{G} \times \tilde{G} \stackrel{p \times p}{\longrightarrow} G \times G \stackrel{m}{\longrightarrow} G
$$
where $m: G \times G \to G$ is your group operation.  Since $\tilde{G} \times \tilde{G}$ is simply connected, a lift of $f$ to $\tilde{f}: \tilde{G} \times \tilde{G} \to \tilde{G}$ exists and is unique with the property that $\tilde{f}(e_0,e_0)=e_0$.  This $\tilde{f}$ will be your group operation on $\tilde{G}$.  You can prove through some long but formal arguments that this is associative, has identity $e_0$, and has all inverses.
But to your main question, the choice of point $e_0$ from the fiber dictates the lift $\tilde{f}$, so different choices of fiber-point will give you different operations on $\tilde{G}$.  The group structure on $\tilde{G}$ is not unique in a global since:  it is only unique after you make a choice of $e_0 \in p^{-1}(e)$.  In your example,  you recover the "ordinary" operation of addition in $\mathbb{R}$ by choosing $0$ as your basepoint in the fiber. Other choices of basepoint "translate" this operation around to a different operation.  In short, you should not expect the group operation to be traditional $+$ in $\mathbb{R}$ if you choose a basepoint different from $0$.
In your case of choosing $2$ as the special fiber-point in $\mathbb{R}$, you need to chase down the definition of the map $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \stackrel{\pi \times \pi}{\longrightarrow} S^1 \times S^1 \stackrel{m}{\longrightarrow} S^1$ and its lift.  In this case,
$$
f(a,b)= e^{2\pi i (a+b)}.
$$
The unique lift $\tilde{f} : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\tilde{f}(2,2)=2$ is simply $\tilde{f}(a,b)=a+b-2$.  You can check this by computing $\pi \circ \tilde{f}$ and seeing that you get back $f$.  Hence your group operation in $\mathbb{R}$ with basepoint $2$ is the operation $\odot$ defined by
$$
a \odot b = a+b-2.
$$
You can check that this does give a group operation on $\mathbb{R}$ with identity $2$.  (And, in fact, this is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ with its ordinary rule of addition.)

Thank you for your answer! But I wonder what is the explicit form of the operation for my example $\pi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow S^1$? I mean, if I choose base point $\tilde{e}=2$ how to determine $\tilde{f}$?

Fair question.  I will try to edit my answer to include.
